# Finding the start and end point of the longest consecutive set of numbers in a large binary set in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary

I'm trying to find the start and end point of the longest consecutive set of numbers in a large binary set using Python 3. At the moment I have found the longest consecutive number of 1's and 0's, and now I must find where the start and end points for each number is. So far my code is:

For 1's:

```
def getMaxSegmentLength(readable):
    current_length = 0
    max_length = 0


    for x in readable:
        if x == '1':
            current_length += 1
        else:
            max_length = max(max_length, current_length)
            current_length = 0

        return max(max_length, current_length)


def main():
    with open('C:/01.txt', 'r') as inputf:
        s = inputf.read()
        n = getMaxSegmentLength(s)
    print("The longest streak of 1's = " + str(n))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

For 0's:

```
def getMaxSegmentLength(readable):
    current_length = 0
    max_length = 0


    for x in readable:
        if x == '0':
            current_length += 1
        else:
            max_length = max(max_length, current_length)
            current_length = 0

        return max(max_length, current_length)


def main():
    with open('C:/01.txt', 'r') as inputf:
        s = inputf.read()
        m = getMaxSegmentLength(s)
    print("The longest streak of 0's = " + str(m))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This code finds the longest consecutive set of numbers in a very large binary set which is contained in a separate file. I also know how many 0's and 1's there are in total, and I have not started the next step which is to find the start and end points. Any help is much appreciated as I am new to Python 3.

Comment: I think you need [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-enumerate.html).

Answer (score 0):

Simple, keep track of where a streak of 1 starts and a variable (max_streak) to keep the max streak's start point. Every time a bigger streak is found update max_streak.

```
def getMaxSegmentLength(readable, digit):
'''find the longest streak of digit in the readable string'''
    current_length = 0
    max_length = 0

    starts_at= -1
    max_starts_at= -1

    for i, x in enumerate(readable):
        if x == digit:
            current_length += 1
            if current_length == 1:
                starts_at = i

        elif max_length < current_length:
            max_length = current_length
            max_starts_at = starts_at
            current_length = 0

    if max_length < current_length:
        max_length = current_length
        max_starts_at = starts_at

    max_ends_at = max_starts_at+max_length-1

    # return a tuple of start point and end point index
    return max_starts_at, max_ends_at


def main():
    with open('F:/input.txt', 'r') as inputf:
        s = inputf.read()

        # check for 1's
        n = getMaxSegmentLength(s, '1')
        print("The longest streak of 1's = " + str(n))

        # check for 0's
        n = getMaxSegmentLength(s, '0')
        print("The longest streak of 0's = " + str(n))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression to match each sequence, and then update a dict for the relevant digit:

```
import re

# example input string
input = "00111101100010100010101111011011011"

best = {
    "0": { "start": 0, "len": 0 },
    "1": { "start": 0, "len": 0 }
};
for m in re.compile(r"(.)\1*").finditer(input):
    if best[m.group()[0]]["len"] < len(m.group()):
        best[m.group()[0]] = { "start": m.start(), "len": len(m.group()) }

print (best)
```

Output:

```
{'1': {'start': 2, 'len': 4}, '0': {'start': 9, 'len': 3}}
```